# помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с функцией из кода игры "ракетка-мяч"

Tags: python, python-3.x

вся суть игры заключается в том, что мячик отлетает от ракетки и стенок.

Вот ее код (он из книги  'Python для детей. Самоучитель по программированию. Бриггс Д.'):

```
from tkinter import*
import random
import time

class Ball:
    def __init__(self, canvas, paddle, color):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.paddle = paddle
        self.id = canvas.create_oval(10, 10, 25, 25, fill=color)
        self.canvas.move(self.id, 245, 100)
        starts = [-3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3]
        random.shuffle(starts)
        self.x = starts[0]
        self.y = -3
        self.canvas_height = self.canvas.winfo_height()
        self.canvas_width = self.canvas.winfo_width()
        self.hit_bottom = False


    def hit_paddle(self, pos):
        paddle_pos = self.canvas.coords(self.paddle.id)
        if pos[2] >= paddle_pos[0] and pos[0] <= paddle_pos[2]:
            if pos[3] >= paddle_pos[1] and pos[3] <= paddle_pos[3]:
                return True
            return False

    def draw(self):
        self.canvas.move(self.id, self.x, self.y)
        pos = self.canvas.coords(self.id)
                
        if pos[0] <= 0:
            self.x = 3
        if pos[2] >= self.canvas_width:
            self.x = -3
        if pos[1] <= 0:
            self.y = 3
        if pos[3] >= self.canvas_height:
            self.hit_bottom = True
        
        if self.hit_paddle(pos) == True:
            num = [-3, -4, -6, -8, -6, -4, -3]
            for i in num:
                self.y = i               

class Paddle:
    def __init__(self, canvas, color):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.id = canvas.create_rectangle(0,0,100,10, fill=color)
        self.canvas.move(self.id, 200, 460)
        self.x = 0
        self.canvas_width = self.canvas.winfo_width()
        self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Left>', self.turn_left)
        self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Right>', self.turn_right)
        
    def draw(self):
        self.canvas.move(self.id, self.x, 0)
        pos = self.canvas.coords(self.id)
        if pos[0] <= 0:
            self.x = 0
        elif pos[2] >= self.canvas_width:
            self.x = 0
    
    def turn_left(self, evt):
        self.x = -2
        
    def turn_right(self, evt):
        self.x = 2
    
tk = Tk()
tk.title("Игра")
tk.resizable(0, 0)
tk.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)
canvas = Canvas(tk, width=450, height=560, bd=0, highlightthickness=0, bg='grey')
canvas.pack()
tk.update()

paddle = Paddle(canvas, 'violet')
ball = Ball(canvas, paddle, 'white')
tk.update()

def sleep(event):
    while 1:
        if ball.hit_bottom == False:
            ball.draw()
            paddle.draw()
            
        if ball.hit_bottom == True:
            canvas.create_rectangle(120, 230, 320, 295, fill='grey')
            canvas.create_rectangle(140, 250, 300, 275, fill='white')
            id = canvas.create_text(220, 260, text="Конец игры", fill="black", font=('Helvetica 17 bold'))
            tk.update()
            time.sleep(0.7)
            
            canvas.itemconfig(id, fill='red')
            tk.update()
            time.sleep(0.7)
            
        tk.update_idletasks()
        tk.update()
        time.sleep(0.01)
    
canvas.bind_all('<Button-1>', sleep)
```

никак не могу понять:
1)как так переменная "pos" из одной функции(draw) может быть аргументом другой. Разве такое возможно? Или дело в том, что обе функции в одном классе?
2)почему мы в "self.canvas.coords(self.paddle.id)" передаем в качестве аргумента "self.paddle.id" и это работает, если переменной paddle.id в этом классе нет(но она есть в классе Paddle). То есть с помощью self можно обращаться даже к переменным из других классов?

```
    def hit_paddle(self, pos):
        paddle_pos = self.canvas.coords(self.paddle.id)
        if pos[2] >= paddle_pos[0] and pos[0] <= paddle_pos[2]:
            if pos[3] >= paddle_pos[1] and pos[3] <= paddle_pos[3]:
                return True
            return False
```

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Не ясно, что вас смущает в "как так переменная "pos" из одной функции(draw) может быть аргументом другой. Разве такое возможно?" - Функции "одного порядка" могут вызывать друг друга. Можете также почитать про параметры (переменная в вызове функции в месте вызова) и аргументы (она же уже в `def` функции) еще. В целом советую почитать про области видимости, вас они явно интересуют.